# Python 3.4. Win32. Take DNS addreses from DHCP

Tags: python

To set something in my nic's wmi library. I'm turning on DHCP using:

```
    nic.EnableDHCP()
```

I'm setting static settings using:

```
    nic.EnableStatic(IPAddress=[ip],SubnetMask=[subnetmask])
    nic.SetGateways(DefaultIPGateway=[gateway])
```

I'm setting static DNS using:

```
    nic.SetDNSServerSearchOrder(DNSServerSearchOrder = dnsServers)
```

But I don't know, how to set dynamic assign DNS IP. When I turn on DHCP, then DNS are still static.

How can I set the DHCP DNS?